# How do I stop stacktraces truncating in logs

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

Lots of times in Java logs I'll get something like:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: failed batch
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeBatch(jdbcStatement.java:1102)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(jdbcPreparedStatement.java:514)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
    ... 113 more
```

Does anyone know how to get the full stacktrace showing (i.e. show the other 113 lines)?

---

The [JavaDocs (for Java 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) for Throwable have a pretty detailed explanation of what's going on.

Comment: the other 113 lines are **already in** the stack trace if you check the previous logged lines

Answer (score 81, accepted):

When you see '...113 more', that means that the remaining lines of the 'caused by' exception are identical to the remaining lines from that point on of the parent exception.

For example, you'll have

```
com.something.XyzException
  at ...
  at ...
  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
  at ... <the other 113 lines are here>...
Caused by: <the above>.
```

The two stack traces 'meet' at AbstractBatcher.executeBatch, line 242, and then from then on the upward call trace is the same as the wrapping exception.

Comment: What? The cause is the same as the wrapping exception? I didn't got it... The couse should show the line where the problem is from, what it not showing when truncating the stacktrace. I'm having this problem and would like to understand this answer, if someone could reformulate it... Thanks! By the way, this answer seem not to show how to print the full stacktrace.

Comment: @TomBrito you ARE seeing the full stacktrace -- you have two exceptions, one inside the other. If the stack trace of the inner (wrapped) exception is A B C D E F G, and the outer exception's stack trace is A B C Z, then you'll see OuterException with the stack trace Z C B A, "caused by" InnerException with the stack trace "G F E D C ... 'then 2 more'". Those 2 more are A and B, from the outer stack trace, and they are ommitted for brevity.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. I've absolutely run into situations where the remaining lines are NOT identical. In this situation, the solution was to increase the maximum depth of the stack trace, as Nikita Koksharov points out, below, by using the -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth VM Option.

Comment: what a terrible answer

Answer (score 35):

Increase `-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth` JVM option.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? This is exactly the answer. Set to -1 for an unlimited depth.

Comment: maybe "-1" doesn't work anymore in recent java versions?

Comment: -1 is out of range for jdk16. Message appearing: `-1 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1073741823 ]`. Max range is 1073741823 maybe.

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work in Tomcat? I tried `JAVA_OPTS=" -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=2000 "` and `CATALINA_OPTS=" -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=2000 "` but neither worked.

Answer (score 22):

Apache's [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) provides a nice util method [ExceptionUtils.printRootCauseStackTrace()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#printRootCauseStackTrace(java.lang.Throwable)) which prints a nested stacktrace 'upside down'. The result is much more intuitive.

If you see the result next to the original out of the printStackTrace() method, it will be clear where the '113 more' lines went.

Answer (score 14):

I like the example found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29):

```
HighLevelException: MidLevelException: LowLevelException
         at Junk.a(Junk.java:13)
         at Junk.main(Junk.java:4)
 Caused by: MidLevelException: LowLevelException
         at Junk.c(Junk.java:23)
         at Junk.b(Junk.java:17)
         at Junk.a(Junk.java:11)
         ... 1 more
 Caused by: LowLevelException
         at Junk.e(Junk.java:30)
         at Junk.d(Junk.java:27)
         at Junk.c(Junk.java:21)
         ... 3 more
```

Basically in the source code, `main` calls `function a` which calls `function b` which calls ... which calls `function e`.
`Function e` throws a `LowLevelException` which causes function c to catch the `LowLevelException` and throw a `MidLevelException` (wrapping the `LowLevelException` instance inside of the `MidLevelException` instance. The `Exception` class has a constructor that is capable of taking in a different exception, wrapping it). This causes function a to catch the `MidLevelException` and throw a `HighLevelException` which now wraps the previous two `Exception` instances.

As noted in the other answers, the stack trace isn't really truncated, you are seeing the full stack trace. The `.. .3 more` in my example is there because it would be redundant otherwise. If you wanted to be redundant and waste output lines, `.. 3 more` could be substituted with

```
at Junk.b(Junk.java:17)
at Junk.a(Junk.java:11)
at Junk.main(Junk.java:4)
```

But there is no need to output these three lines, because they are already implied.

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful to get the whole picture. Get a full stack trace of the Exception **and** the cause (which often shows repeated lines from the main Exception, but can be helpful).

```
        ... catch( Exception e) ...

        ... catch( NoClassDefFoundError e)
        {

                for(StackTraceElement ste: e.getStackTrace())
                {
                    System.out.println(ste);
                }

                if( e.getCause()!=null )
                {
                    for(StackTraceElement ste: e.getCause().getStackTrace())
                    {
                        System.out.println(ste);
                    }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

In a blog post I just described [how to get more than just "BatchUpdateException: failed batch"](http://inoio.de/blog/2012/11/16/how-to-get-rid-of-hibernate-genericjdbcexception/): set `hibernate.jdbc.factory_class=org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcherFactory` to disable batching in hibernate.
Normally one can use `BatchUpdateException.getNextException` to get the reason of the failure, but in some cases this may return `null`. Then it's useful to disable batching completely.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It may solve his situation in real life, so adding it as a comment to his question could be more helpful than posting an answer