# Logging Pattern - not logging the cause

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am having some issues with logging.  After reviewing JBoss Seam source code, I believe the problem is there.  I would like to see JBoss Seam migrate to SLF4J since Hibernate code already uses it.

I think the issue is I don't have log4j available and I don't have Logback configured to use JDK logging.

I guess for the time-being, I need to use one of those to get the logs functioning again.

Actually, on second thought, I will just use a static logger.  The advantage of the JBoss Seam logger (once it works), is that it can process EL, but honestly, I'm not using that anywhere in my logs.  It is a nice feature to have, but I can still get what I want without support for EL.

Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern is fine. Which version of logback are you using? Can you show the exact line of code where you issue the logging request? As in:

logger.error("some exception", e);

From the above it is not clear how logback is involved in logging the exception. You seem to be throwing an exception but not logging it...

Comment: Hi Ceki - This is Walter, the one that will help with the documentation :).  I am using Jetty 6 along with JBoss Seam 2.2.0.GA

Comment: Are you using logback-access or logback-classic? Logback-access cannot print exceptions. It integrates with the container for access logging (the logs about who accessed which page and when).

Comment: Ok, my current setup is using both the classic and access.  All of my web-based projects inherit from a web pom project which declares the logback-access dependency.  All of my other libraries use the logback-classic dependency.


Walter

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your question, but I found the following useful in this context.

- [Printing full stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043378/print-full-call-stack-on-printstacktrace)
- [Chained Exceptions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html)

I also think that the answer you want either depends on lowering the logging level (so that you have more detailed logs) or more detailed logging where the logger is used. That is, it has nothing to do with the format. But this is a guess and likely wrong.