# Renew security token on Java after failed try

Tags: java, security, token, keystore, pkcs#11

I have developed code to check if a certain security token is found in the PC prior to a certain operation. The code I am using right now to get the keystore is:

```
    private KeyStore getKeyStore() {
            try {
                    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",getProvider()); //$NON-NLS-1$
                    char [] pin = "mypin".toCharArray();
                    keyStore.load(null, pin);

                    return keyStore;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return null;
    }

    private Provider getProvider() throws ClassNotFoundException, 
        NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class<?> lclass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent().loadClass("sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11"); //$NON-NLS-1$
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Constructor constructor = lclass.getConstructor(String.class);
            return (Provider) constructor.newInstance(configName);
    }
```

If the security token (a USB smartcard) is present the first time the application tries to access the keystore, it runs smoothly without error; but when the smart card is not present the first time the applications tries to get the token, the `KeyStore.getInstance` raises this exception:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found
at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at es.giro.girlabel.token.Token.getKeyStore(Token.java:120)
at es.giro.girlabel.token.Token.getCertificate(Token.java:156)
at es.giro.girlabel.token.Token.hasToken(Token.java:150)
at es.giro.girlabel.jobs.JobList.getInstance(JobList.java:73)
at es.giro.girlabel.editor.view.LabelListView$10.run(LabelListView.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at es.giro.girlabel.Application.start(Application.java:39)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)


Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: PKCS11 for provider       SunPKCS11-eToken
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
... 35 more
```

After this first try, if I plug back the security token, and retry the operation, I get exactly the same error.

Is the SunPKCS11 class caching some data? If so, is there any way to clear this cache?

Thanks for your attention, and please forgive my spelling. English is not my native language.

EDIT:

The complete stack trace:

```
java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
es.giro.girlabel.token.Token.getKeyStore(Token.java:119)
es.giro.girlabel.token.Token.getCertificate(Token.java:160)
es.giro.girlabel.token.Token.hasToken(Token.java:154)
es.giro.girlabel.jobs.JobList.getInstance(JobList.java:73)
es.giro.girlabel.editor.view.LabelListView$10.run(LabelListView.java:499)
org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
es.giro.girlabel.Application.start(Application.java:39)
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

Comment: The stacktrace is not complete. I assume that the most interesting part is hidden in the "... 35 more" part because NoSuchAlgorithmException is used in this context as a Exception wrapper.

Comment: That's the whole stack trace I get. Even though, I was expecting it when the USB is not present.

Comment: You can print the full stack trace by code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043378/print-full-call-stack-on-printstacktrace/1043461#1043461

Comment: I have added the stack trace using the "getStackTrace" function from the Exception class.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but `Constructor constructor = ...; return (Provider) constructor.newInstance(...)` can be better phrased as `Constructor<Provider> constructor = ...; return constructor.newInstance(...)`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll add it to my code.

Comment: By the way, I have tested in linux the same code, and it works fine, I guess its a driver issue.