# How to set java to show full call stack for exception?

Tags: java

I am getting exception in the log. The stack trace ens with "... 11 more".
But want to see actual 11 more lines, not just "... 11 more".
Is there a way to start java the way that it gives full picture of the call stack on exception?

Comment: How are you logging it?

Comment: Note: If it is a [chained `Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html), those 11 more are the duplicates of the original `Exception` and the wrapper `Exception`. Thus, those 11 lines are already available just before a (or multiple) preceding `caused by`.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience those "11 more" will be duplicates of the same exception.
This is similar to [how to print the full stacktrace in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970361/how-to-print-the-full-stacktrace-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I do not think that is about the duplication of same exception. It looks like: 
 at com. .... .... .... .java:41)
        ... 11 more.
That is about the stack show is abrupt.