# How to display more line in a mac terminal when an error is displayed

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

Right now when I am executing a command and get this error (it doesn't really matter what the error is for this question) :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty$Delegating
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
... 39 more
```

And I want to have access to those 39 more lines. I've already tried to output to a file with "> a.txt", but I had no success.

Comment: Actually, the terminal doesn't hide anything - that's why your output redirection "> a.txt" doesn't help (note though that errors are often printed to stderr instead of stdout). Here you are dealing with java exceptions and a quick googling yields [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970361/how-to-print-the-full-stacktrace-in-java#2970366), see the comments to the question there for further similar links and explanation of what's happening.