# Android ADB Logcat-- showing full logcat

Tags: android, error-handling, adb

I'm using 'adb -d logcat' in terminal to view my applications log files. Recently, I've been hitting a large block of Runtime Errors- all of which I cannot see for some reason. It just stops at the end with '...30 more' :

> [ 08-11 12:27:45.500  8801:0x2261 E/AndroidRuntime ]
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
>       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
>       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
>       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
>       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
>       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
>       at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
>       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
>       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
>       at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
>       at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout
>       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
>       ... 30 more

How can I view the '... 30 more' problems that I'm receiving in the logcat??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043378/print-full-call-stack-on-printstacktrace see this

Answer (score 2):

From the question [Print full call stack on printStackTrace()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043378/print-full-call-stack-on-printstacktrace) :

> [here is an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437756/how-do-i-stop-stacktraces-truncating-in-logs) of the 'caused by' and '... *n* more'
>   lines in the printed trace.  see also the [JavaDoc for
>   printStackTrace](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()).  you might not have any work to do.
>
> > Note the presence of lines containing the characters "...". These
> >     lines indicate that the remainder of the stack trace for this
> >     exception matches the indicated number of frames from the bottom of
> >     the stack trace of the exception that was caused by this exception
> >     (the "enclosing" exception). This shorthand can greatly reduce the
> >     length of the output in the common case where a wrapped exception is
> >     thrown from same method as the "causative exception" is caught.