# Eclipse console error message limitation

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse IDE and the console truncates my error message.
I want to get to the root of the error but all that it says is '5 more.' How can I make it so that eclipse shows all the error messages?

Thanks!!

For example:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: 
        
at com.quantcast.rmr.MRStep.start(MRStep.java:1281) 
         at com.quantcast.rmr.MRFlow.job(MRFlow.java:669) 
     
    at com.implicitlabs.rmr.Job.exec(Job.java:1481)
     
    at com.implicitlabs.rmr.Job.startExecution(Job.java:492)
     
    at com.implicitlabs.rmr.JobStartup.callStartup(JobStartup.java:38)
     
    at com.implicitlabs.rmr.Job.main(Job.java:422)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: 
     
    at com.implicitlabs.rmr.Job.executeStep(Job.java:2878)
     
    at com.implicitlabs.rmr.Job.go(Job.java:1297)
     
    at com.quantcast.rmr.MRStep.start(MRStep.java:1279)
     
    **... 5 more**

Comment: What is shown is all there is to show. The `5 more` are the ones under the IOException following `start()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437756/how-do-i-stop-stacktraces-truncating-in-logs.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the property of the error, that should show the whole text or at least a field on which you can use cut and paste