# How to print all java exceptions on the terminal?

Tags: java, cmd

I've noticed that whenever an exception is thrown on the terminal, I often get an abbreviate failure trace such as this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

What I want to know is how to print all of the trace, including those `... 13 more`.

EDIT: This post has been identified as a possible duplicate of [Print full call stack on printStackTrace()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043378/print-full-call-stack-on-printstacktrace) . I did read the latter but didn't find an answer to my question, I only found information on why it happens.

Comment: Actually.. it will print entier thing .. what is stopping here is your console... Increase your console's page lines (or make it unlimited), then you will get enterire list

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043378/print-full-call-stack-on-printstacktrace

Comment: And how can I implement those changes to my console @PavanKumarK? I'm using win7, by the way, perhaps it's relevant to the question.

Comment: Why do you want to see 13 more, when they are already present in the printed lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `Throwable` object (the `Exception` in your case) to a method like this:

```
static void printFullTrace(Throwable throwable){
    for(StackTraceElement element: throwable())
        System.out.println(element);
}
```

The truth is that you are already seeing the whole stack trace in those lines, because a part of it is repeated and so omitted for brevity. You can understand better the mechanism [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/437767/1003123).

Comment: Although this is indeed quite useful information, what I am looking for, if it even exists, is a simple way to make my command line print all the trace, instead of writing "...13 more"
@PavanKumarK said in the comments that you could increase your console's page lines but hasn't developed his answer yet... Is it possible?

Comment: @Maslor: I have added it

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraces = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
for (StackTraceElement element : stackTraces) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative simple method that doesn't require adding code to my application, if it exists.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()  is that enough, or  I am missing something that you know, but do not want to share ?

Answer (score 0):

You can print the whole stack Traces by below method. Reading the [Java Doc for printStackTrace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) will tell why is this designed this way.

```
void printAllTraces(Throwable throwable) {
       StackTraceElement[] stackTraces = throwable.getStackTrace();
       for (StackTraceElement stackTrace: stackTraces) {
          System.out.println(stackTrace); 
       }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative simple method that doesn't require adding code to my application, if it exists.

Comment: printStackTrace can give only this much and this  is designed in order to be concise. So without adding little code I am afraid there is no way you get the full stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

The standard Windows console (cmd) is very short of features, you need to install a console on steroids like ones that are out there, so you'll be able to have a larger scrollback. Take a look into the alternatives listed [here](http://www.nextofwindows.com/4-better-windows-console-tools-alternatives-to-windows-built-in-command-prompt).

Personally I use [cmder](http://gooseberrycreative.com/cmder/), that is not in the list, but you must test them all and peek which fit you better.