# AccessControlException after migration to Spring 4.2.4

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

After migration from Spring 4.2.3 to 4.2.4 I cannot run my aplication on Google App Engine

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: xxx.xxx.configuration.AppConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:410)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:206)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:179)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:136)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:469)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.reflect.annotation")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:382)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:572)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:55)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1525)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(ReflectUtil.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(ReflectUtil.java:164)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getInvocationHandler(Proxy.java:822)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.synthesizeAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:1364)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:498)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.BeanAnnotationHelper.isBeanAnnotated(BeanAnnotationHelper.java:35)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.isMatch(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:487)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$ConditionalCallbackFilter.accept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:190)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitMethods(Enhancer.java:898)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:509)
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanFactoryAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:249)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:107)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:400)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the rest of the stack trace beyond '.. 26 more'?

Comment: "When you see '...26 more', that means that the remaining lines of the 'caused by' exception are identical to the remaining lines from that point on of the parent exception."
http://stackoverflow.com/a/437767/3232040

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring bug, fixed but not yet released so either wait for 4.2.5 or revert to 4.2.3: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13829

Comment: It does provide an answer: what part of "wait for Spring 4.2.5 or revert to 4.2.3" is not a clear and direct answer to the problem? There is no other solution, nothing the application developer can do since it's a fundamental flaw in this release of Spring. The link I provide is meant only to provide detailed information if you are curious, or evidence if you want to make sure of what I'm saying; all essential information is already here.

Answer (score 2):

So the obvious is that something is trying to use the 'sun.reflect.annotation' package which is not on the [JRE whitelist](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist). The question remains as to what, as none of the classes in spring-framework use this package explicitly (from grepping the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework)).

The stack trace indicates the culprit as the following line:

```
Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation) instanceof SynthesizedAnnotationInvocationHandler))
```

As a guess, the JDK defines *sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler* as a dynamic proxy implementation of Annotation. So it seems this is related to the annotation being synthesized, when the method checks for that annotation's invocation handler and ends up accessing the 'sun.reflect.annotation' package.

Hopefully this may lead someone to a more complete answer.