# Hibernate - during an exception log sql and all parameters

Tags: hibernate, exception

How do I get hibernate to fully log all details when an exception is thrown?
I would like to see the full (not truncated) sql and the full (not truncated) parameters.

ie Hibernate is throwing:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
long stack trace
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: Incorrect string value:
Query is: blah blah blah ...
```

I don't want to see any "..." there. I want to see the *full* sql and the *full* parameter list.

This is an unchecked exception. What is the configuration needed for this (and any other hibernate exceptions) to be fully logged?

As this is production code I would prefer not changing the jdbc driver to net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy

(Left out the truncated sql + parameters for clarity)

Comment: Use a debugger and let is catch the unhandled exception?

Comment: you've never worked in production, huh?

Comment: You never used a debugger in production? Good luck... Since it crashes anyway, you could take a crash dump using [WER LocalDumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps?redirectedfrom=MSDN). You can then do a [strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings) search with the partial string you have.

Comment: I cannot  slow mine down hoping to catch a one off user error that happens randomly. this is a caught exception, the prod instance isn't crash and burning, so a crash dump isn't viable either.

Comment: Please add to question your current `hibernate.properties` or `hibernate.cfg.xml` (or equivalent) settings and the logging type (e.g. log4j) and logging level used for Hibernate.

Comment: Something to try: Set `-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1` as a JVM parameter, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437756#answer-50128144). Can't say whether this will actually fix this issue but it's worth ruling in or out...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) library.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>p6spy</groupId>
  <artifactId>p6spy</artifactId>
  <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The idea is wrapping the data source you use for Hibernate with p6spy proxy which logs everything as you configure it.

It may look like the following code if you use Hikari pool:

```
DataSource ds = new P6DataSource(new HikariDataSource(dsConfig));
```

The configuration of p6spy lays in `spy.properties` file which should be found in the root of your classpath (in the root of the jar file).

Here is the example of the `spy.properties`:

```
# suppress inspection "UnusedProperty" for whole file
#appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.StdoutLogger
appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.Slf4JLogger
excludecategories=info,debug,result,resultset
logMessageFormat=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.CustomLineFormat
customLogMessageFormat=%(category) | connection %(connectionId) | \u001b[33m%(sqlSingleLine)\u001b[0m | %(executionTime) ms
```

As you can see, it is possible to configure how p6spy writes logs with the chosen appender.

If everything configured well, you see SQL queries and corresponding parameters in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Generally,(...) is used to indicate repeated logs lines in the stack trace, try increasing the value of
`-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth` JVM parameter